# SQL - How to join foreign keyed data, with the column names of the parent table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
RUNS

ID  numb   bay0  bay1  bay2
-----------------------------
1    55     aa    bb    cc
2    66     gg   NULL   dd
3    77     dd    bb   NULL

DATA
ID  run_id  serial  data
------------------------------
1     2       gg     xx
2     2       dd     xx
```

DATA.run_id is a foreign key pointing to RUNS.ID.

'serial' and the value of 'bay%' are foreign keys pointing to another table 'products'.

What I would like is an output like this:

```
OUTPUT
ID  run_id  serial  data  bay
------------------------------
1     2       gg     xx   bay0
2     2       dd     xx   bay2
```

Such that the column headers of the first table are put into the output rows of the second tables data.

I have been playing around with alot of queries to get this to work like getting the column headers:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME =  'a'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'b'
AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'bay%'
```

But ultimately I can't see how I am going to get/merge/concatenate this output. Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Its `SQL chapter 2` so go and [read the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) SO **is not a free coding service**

Comment: Is **every values** in 3 columns `bay0`, `bay1`, `bay2` unique? If not, what is your output, if in `row 2` of table `RUNS`, column `bay0` has value `dd`, not `gg` ?

Comment: @NayruLove, the values in the 'bay%' columns will never be the same for one row. Successive rows could use the same values. I will add a line to show the possiblilty

Comment: @ RiggsFolly, I think this is abit more complex than a join, as the serial can appear in any order in both tables.

Comment: You have fixed count of `bayX` columns? Or your want query that will work with any count?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, The number of 'bay' columns are fixed.

Comment: See normalisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If number of columns is fixed you can do this:

```sql
SELECT
  data.id, data.run_id, data.serial, data.data,
  CASE data.serial
      WHEN runs.bay0 THEN 'bay0'
      WHEN runs.bay1 THEN 'bay1'
      WHEN runs.bay2 THEN 'bay2'
      ELSE NULL
  END AS bay
FROM
  data
  JOIN runs ON (data.run_id = runs.id)
```

Just list all possible variants in `CASE` statement. Not elegant, but will work until you add/remove `bayX` column to `data` table.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Thanks mate! The bay numbers being manually isnt a problem for now, and I think I can work out how to automate getting them by incorporating the query I linked in my main question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    ( ID  int,  run_id  int,  serial  varchar(2),  data  varchar(2))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    ( ID ,  run_id ,  serial ,  data )
VALUES
    (1, 2, 'gg', 'xx'),
    (2, 2, 'dd', 'xx')
;


DECLARE @Table2 TABLE 
    ( ID  int,  serial  int,  bay0  varchar(2),  bay1  varchar(2), bay2  varchar(2))
;

INSERT INTO @Table2
    ( ID ,  serial ,  bay0 ,  bay1 ,bay2)
VALUES
    (1, 55, 'aa', 'bb','cc'),
    (2, 66, 'gg', NULL,'dd')
;


SELECT T.ID,T.run_id,T.serial,T.DATA,tt.COL FROM @Table1 t
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT COL,VAL FROM @Table2
cross apply (values('bay0',bay0),('bay1',bay1),('bay2',bay2))cs(COL,VAL)
WHERE col <> 'BAY1')tt
on T.serial = TT.VAL
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get errors with this one, both on my server and on sqlfiddle (MySql 5.6)

Comment: I have given this one in MS SQL server . can you please convert this one in any conversion tool